# How to create hotkey for button by modifying xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, hotkeys, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to learn keybinding in WPF by a simple example.

here is my XAML file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="myNewCommand"></RoutedUICommand>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource myNewCommand}" Executed="Button_Click"></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding myNewCommand}" Key="B" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding myNewCommand}" Click="Button_Click"  Content="Click Here"/>

</Grid>
```

And this is code behind for Button_Click :

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
```

I get the "hello" message when I click on button, but no response when I press "B" on keyboard.
I want to have this binding without changing the Button_click, can I do it just in XAML? how?

Comment: I haven't used InputBindings before, but myNewCommand is a `StaticResource`. Your `InputBindings` command should probably read `{StaticResource myNewCommand}`, like it does in your `CommandBindings`

Answer (score 3):

Your command bindings aren't correct. You should replace `{Binding myNewCommand}` with `{Binding Source={StaticResource myNewCommand}}`. It is also not necessary to have a Click handler on the button when you have already bound a command.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="myNewCommand"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource myNewCommand}"
                    Executed="MyCommandExecuted"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource myNewCommand}}" Key="B" />
</Window.InputBindings>
<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource myNewCommand}}"
            Content="Click Here"/>
</Grid>
```

The `Executed` handler:

```
private void MyCommandExecuted(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```